# Crashlytics on Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, crashlytics

I am trying to use Fabric on my current Game Project which is based on Libgdx Framework. I am not sure where should I put instruction codes to which gradle file.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
    // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

    // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
```

First of all this buildscript block exists in build gradle of Project, not for android. Since I put these into parent gradle file, android gradle file can not recognize the library.

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
```

I can only add these code blocks into the whole gradle file again which is shown below.

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}
```

Could you help me to use Fabric into my game properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject few lines of code in your root `build.gradle` of LibGDX project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }          //<- 1st
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'         // <- 2nd       
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "MyGDXTest"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }      // <-- 3rd
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'                //<-- 4th

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {  //<--5th
            transitive = true;
        }    
    }
}
```

Save and sync/refresh your gradle project.

You can also inject `crashlytics` dependency(5th block) in app level `build.gradle` file, by default dependencies tag not present there in LibGDX project.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all of these blocks inside your app level build.gradle file. Here is an example of the gradle file of my app where I have set up Fabric with Crashlytics up and working:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
} 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourappid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Make sure you have formed your build.gradle file in a similar fashion and everything will work after you sync your project.

Comment: Make it brief, why are you adding external artifact... more dependency more confusion...:)

Comment: This is a real working project. I believe it's better to look at the complete picture looks and figure out how do things work. Moreover, the OP already knows which dependencies and blocks of code he needs to add. By looking at the code I provided, he'll easily figure out the rest.

Comment: may be that is part of your working project. but many external artifact lile `firebase-ads`, `appintro`, `constraint-layout`,  lower version of  `crashlytics` and `libs compilation` are not required.

Comment: Crashlytics comes together with Fabric. Indeed, I can delete the rest if you believe that they can be misleading.

Comment: I am talking about lower version of `Crashlytics`, I believe that external artifact that not required here can mislead noobs developer.

Answer (score 0):

The fabric dependency should be added in the app level gradle ( **not** the project level gradle ). Also remember to add your API key in the manifest.

**So your app level gradle should look like this:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
}
```